# magento 2 layer navigation not showing

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

in Magento 2 Layer navigation not showing. I set **`is_anchor Yes`**

I **`Reindexed`** i get success response also

**`Flush`** the cache delete cache folder also

What i need to do ?

Comment: have you added products with that filtered categories?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting

Comment: for that category which you want to set on layered navigation, you need to assign product that cateogry

Comment: I already assigned product but not showing any layer navigation atleast it should show price right that also nit showing

Comment: check if price attribute is set filtered(with Result)

Comment: in other category it display but my new category it not showing

Comment: @Develop if you have assigned product and it shows in other categories too !! then check your category 's display settings. `edit your category -> go to display settings -> check display mode -> it should be Products only or static block and Products only`

Comment: I Set Product Only but same no changes